If all order p subgroups are conjugate, do we have any constraint on p's power on group $G$'s order?
Background from here, the question is related to if all order 4 subgroups are conjugate, then what property do we have.
A natural following up question from that post is:

If all order 4 subgroups are conjugate and non-normal, let's say |$G$|=$2^nm$
, What does this group satisfy these condition looks like? Does it impose an upper bound on the 2-valuation of |$G$|
(It seemed to impose a constraint on the group structure and force the $n$ not very large)?

More generally,

If all order $p^a$ subgroups are conjugate and non-normal,let's say |$G$|=$p^nm$,
What does this group satisfy these condition looks like? Does it impose an upper bound on the $p$-valuation of |$G$| (It seemed to impose a constraint on the group structure and force the $n$ not very large)?

$G$ is supposed to be finite, but if we can find a $G$ that's infinite and satisfy all order $p^a$ subgroup are conjugate, then the better.

Previous question specified subgroupsnof order 4 were not normal and conjugate. You omit that, meaning that the answer is a trivial "no" because we can take arbitrarily large cyclic groups.

You are asserting it imposes conditions. "it does impose" mean you claim that the condition is definitely imposed. Did you mean to ask ("does it impose"), or to assert ("it does impose")? English is not commutative.

The answer to your question is no. For any integers $a,n$  with $1 \le a \le n$ there are examples of finite groups with Sylow $p$-subgroups of order $p^n$ in which all subgroups of order $p^a$ are conjugate and non-normal.
To see this let $q$ be a prime with $p^n|(q-1)$. Then the automorphism group of a cyclic group $C_q$ of order $q$ has elements of order $p^n$. Let $G = C_q \rtimes_\phi C_{p^n}$ be the semidirect product in which $\phi$ maps a generator of $C_{p^n}$ to an automorphism of $C_q$ of order $p^n$. Then for all $1 \le a \le n$, the subgroups of $G$ of order $p^a$ are conjugate and non-normal (there are exactly $q$ of them).

Hello, I don't understand semidirect product, so I don't know what's the $q$ conjugate of them.

I think you need to learn about semidirect products.

Suppose in your example, these $q$ element are conjugated together, which means I can find find some $g \in S$($S$ being Sylow $p$-subgroup),  such that $gH_jg^{-1} = H_i$, that's still not the same as in every possible group that satisfy the condition(order $p^a$ subgroups are conjugate), I can just find  some $g \in S$,  such that $gH_jg^{-1} = H_i$ ?

I don't understand your question. The Sylow $p$-subgroups are cyclic and hence abelian, and each of the $q$ Sylow $p$-subgroups contains a unique subgroup of order $p^a$.

I kind of understand the group structure you describe now, but you said my new question is the same as this one(the new one you comment to), my new question is,
for every possible group that satisfy the condition(order $p^a$
subgroups are conjugate),can I always find some ∈
, such that $gH_jg^{-1}=H_i$?

Sorry, I deleted my comment to your new question. The answer to your new question is yes in this example, but not in general. I can find examples in which it is false with $a=1$ and $a=n-1$, but at the moment not otherwise.

I reopened that post, could you answer in that post? Thanks.

I change my answer of this post only to prove $H$ is normal in $S$, does it make sense now?

I watched several video and understand semidirect product is $(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)=(h_1k_1h_2k_1^{-1},k_1k_2)$, but I still have diffculty finding the conjugate subgroup of your group, do you have any resource that talking about conjugation(or conjugate subgroup) in semidirect product group? Thanks.

I've found some constraint on $G$: $H$ must be normal within  Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$.
now focus on one $S$ and completely forget $G$, call all conjugate subgroups reachable by conjugation of $s \in S$ as set $J$,
similar proof for Third Sylow Theorem shows $|J|$=1,
first $S$ acts on $J$ by conjugation and is transitive, shows
$$|S|=|N_H(S)| * |J| $$
so $|J|$ divides $p^n$.
Now restrict the action to $H$, class equation shows:
$$|J|=1+|\text{orbit of other}\ H_i|$$
then $|J| \equiv 1(\mod{p})$,
because |orbit of other $H_i$| is $p^x$, where $0 \le x \le n$, but suppose $H$ also fixes $H'$, $H \subset N(H')$, $H' \subset N(H')$, H' is normal in $N(H')$, H and H' are conjugate, so H=H', which means there will be only 1 one in RHS(H only fixes itself), since $|J|$ divides $p^n \implies |J|=1$, which means $H$ is normal in $S$.

I can't make much sense of this, and it is certainly not an answer to the question that you asked.
